# ImageView меняет свой размер при быстрой прокрутке RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, imageview, утечка-памяти, resize

Изображения изначально парсятся с сайта и выводит их потом в ресайклере Glide. При фиксированном задании размера картинок,например 360*240,что в xml, что в Glid'e, не возникает никаких проблем. Но стоит задать у ImageView в xml параметры, дабы всё подгонялось под любой экран:

```
android:layout_width="match_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

сразу начинаются проблемы. А именно, при быстрой прокрутке размер ImageView, некоторые из изображений становятся маленькими как по ширине, так и по высоте. При плавной прокрутке, такого нет. А если перейти на другое активити и затем вернуться обратно,то при пересоздании списка, все изображения становятся меньшего размера.
Проблема очевидно с памятью, которая забивается изображениями. Но как её решить - не могу понять.

Comment: а картинки хоть большие?

Comment: @Flippy , если бы. 360*240

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/710)